# Which type of reference to use in Java?

Tags: java, android, reference

I have ready some questions here about the use of `WeakReference`, `SoftReference` etc.. However, it is still not clear to me what should I use in the following case:

Consider a master class called `Manager`. There is only one instance of it for the entire application and it contains a lot of other classes (call them `WorkerA`,`WorkerB`...and so on) as members:

```
public class Manager {
     private final WorkerA wA;
     private final WorkerB wB;
     ...
     public Manager()
     {
         wA = new WorkerA(this);
         ...
     }
}
```

so the `Manager` can anytime reach its `Workers` and call their methods.
However, sometimes even the workers have to communicate back to their manager, so all of them contain the same reference to the only instance of the manager:

```
class WorkerA {
   private final Manager mgr;

   public WorkerA(Manager mgr)
   { this.mgr = mgr; }
}
```

The lifetime of the `Manager` = lifetime of the application, it is created once at the beginning and disposed at exit. The Workers are never instantiated anywhere else than inside the manager's constructor.

How is keeping of these cross-references memory demanding? (My app is an Android service which is supposed to run for long time). Is there a better solution with the same functionality?

Comment: First off, your Manager class should be a singleton class. Secondly, once a  `Worker` is created, does it exist until the application exits?

Comment: You'll need memory for the manager and all the instanciated workers since they'll all live during application lifetime. I don't really see your point ?

Comment: As @I.K. mentioned, hold a single, static reference of your `Manager` instance.

Comment: Okay, singleton essentially means having a private constructor and a public static method for instantiating, and anything else? So all the workers then call that static method?

Comment: What is the question here?  'How is keeping of these cross-references memory demanding'.. they are not very memory demanding.  Do not use weak, or soft etc references for this.  Straight object references will be fine.

Comment: Yes - that was the question - can I use Soft or Weak references rather to lower memory cost. There's almost over 50 different workers.

Comment: What takes memory is your workers, not the references from the Manager

Comment: All right, the thing I didn't know if the back-reference from each worker actually has some significant cost to worry about.

Comment: @I.K. Actually not every worker exists until the end of the application. Manager kills some of them during the lifetime.

Comment: Their cost is not significant.  The cost of a field holding a reference will be 64bits on a 64bit cpu per field.  There will also be a very mild cpu cost when the GC runs.  However, the cost increases both for memory usage and cpu when using soft/weak/phantom references.  The time to use those is when you intend to drop the objects at some point and the normal GC life cycle is not enough.  Since you keep the objects for the life of the app, then your approach is already sound.

Comment: @ChrisK Great, thanks for a helpful comment. As I came to Java from C++, I wasn't sure if I can look at the references in Java the same way as at the references in C++. I think that actually answered my question.

Comment: @NumberFour You're welcome.  I will clean the comment up and repost it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cost of a field pointing holding a reference to another object is not significant.

The cost of a field holding a reference will be 64bits on a 64bit cpu per field, less on a 32 bit cpu or when compressed pointers are being used by the virtual machine. There will also be a very mild cpu cost when the GC runs.  This is because the cost of a GC cycle is related to how many live objects exist and the links between them.  However, the cost increases both for memory usage and cpu when using soft/weak/phantom references. This is because they require extra object allocations which are larger than a field and they require special processing during the GC loop which costs cpu time.

The time to use the special weak/soft etc references is when you intend to drop the objects at some point and the normal GC life cycle is not enough. Since you keep the objects for the life of the app, then your approach is already sound.

Comment: Thanks! One last thing - You say, if there are some workers (but very few) which are destroyed by the manager earlier than at application exit, I still shouldn't bother using anything else than a simple object reference?

Comment: If the worker is shutdown, then I would null out the reference to the worker from the manager.  I would assume that the worker knows that it is shutting down?  In which case it can notify the manager itself.  That will be enough for the GC to spot that the object can be cleaned up.  If you cannot hear the shutdown of the worker, then that is the time to use a WeakReference.

Answer (score 1):

As well as making the `Manager` class a singleton class I would not use soft or weak references for the `Worker` objects. The last thing you want is for a `Worker` object's memory to be reclaimed by the garbage collector when you least expect it (i.e. when you invoke that object to do some work!). With ordinary Java references (ie. strong references) this will not happen. The different types of references mentioned here only determine how those reference types interact with the garbage collector: weak references are eagerly reclaimed by the garbage collector whereas soft ones are less eagerly reclaimed.

Since you have also now specified that the `Manager` is responsible for the lifetime of the `Worker` objects then using weak/soft references is even more of a mute point. You only use those type of references when you want to the GC to determine whether a particular objects memory can be reclaimed or not rather than manually trying to do determine that yourself.